# speeding up select query using parallel processing

Tags: java, oracle, java-8

I am running a simple select query to fetch all the values from the table and writing the resultset into CSV file using Java code. Code below -

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
info.setProperty("user", "<username>"); //x_sbe_read
info.setProperty("password", "<password>");

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("<burl>", info); 
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select '/*+ PARALLEL(t,10) */' from <tablename> t");

File resultFile = new File("/tmp/data.csv");
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(resultFile), CEDILLA_CHAR, Character.MIN_VALUE, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
csvWriter.writeAll(rset, false);
csvWriter.close();

rset.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

This table contains data for the past 3 years. One of the ways that I was thinking of speeding up the process is to run a separate thread thereby spinning up 36 threads , each querying 1 month worth of data ( after making sure db can handle 36 connections) and aggregating the result into a single file.

Is there any library within java or oracle function that helps in achieving the same by querying the data in parallel and aggregating the result set.

EDIT:

I used Pentaho and it was able to create a file out of 800K records in a table in 13 minutes on my laptop. This seems to be significantly faster than the code listed above which took more than 30 minutes and did not finish.

Comment: How many rows (and columns and kind of data) are there in the table?

Comment: 8 columns and 800K rows. 6 columns are varchar2 and 2 columns are dates fields. This is one of the tables on which I am experimenting. There are 10 other tables on which I will be using the same strategy. These tables have data ranging from 200K records to 4 million records.

Comment: I suspect you can use some kind of export or table dump utility Oracle might have (I haven't used Oracle db for a while). Did you check the Oracle db manuals or Google search? Also, specify what version of db and the OS.

Comment: I am trying to use java or any other language as I am not allowed to use oracle utilities or pl sql procedures in my enterprise. sorry, should have mentioned that.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch , the db is currently on-prem and we aren't encouraged to use something that runs on-prem for now. So we are planning to use java or any other language to query the db and generate the files. Sorry , I didn't mean not using "oracle" products as such.

Comment: @PunterVicky That does not alter my recommendation. When I am not allowed to use the appropriate tool for the job at hand, then I am no longer interested in continuing said job.

Comment: Even 4M records in a table is not that big especially if your query doesn't have any `WHERE` clauses. Have you measured time needed to dump the largest table in a single thread?

Comment: I tried a running it for 10K records from my laptop and it took 1 minute. I tried running one with 800K records , but terminated it as was taking more than 30 minutes.

Comment: Somethings are showing up for the Google search you might want to look at: _oracle database parallel query_

Comment: I looked up the parallel hints briefly , but I assumed it uses parallel threads where more than one operation is involved such as 1 thread for query , 1 for order by other for group by etc. Please correct me if I am wrong and I'll explore further on that.

Comment: Check this [article on parallelism](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/automating-parallelism), and hope you will something useful in it!

Comment: @PunterVicky but still using parallele hint will speed up your query, select /*+ full( talbe) parallele (table,15) */ col1 from table

Comment: Can you share your whole code (i mean: a program that does the export to csv)?
I would assume that actually fetching the rows from the table is NOT the bottleneck.
However if the flow of the program is:
1. fetch_row -> 2. make some operations to create string -> 3.put string somewhere
then database will be waiting when you execute steps 2 and 3.
That is what you should parallelize - not the fetching part.

Comment: Fetching the entire table sounds like the wrong approach (to whatever task) in the first place. However, the speed problems on the database side may be caused by not using `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`. Besides that, the speed of the network line doesn’t improve by using multiple threads. Neither does using multiple queries for different parts of the table. In fact, in most scenarios I experienced, the number of queries was the biggest performance factor, so using 36 queries instead of one slows down the operation by a factor up to 36, almost independently of the amount of data.

Comment: @piezol shared the code.

Comment: Thanks @Holger. I'll try using TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and CONCUR_READ_ONLY

Comment: So it boils down to the question what does `CSVWriter.writeAll` actually do.

Comment: Thanks Holger , it’s an open source library which I’m using to convert resultset to a CSV file. So it depends on the logic of this method as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think using java is a bad idea. Perhaps you can make a system call from java to execute a sql session that does the job:

```
set term off
set feed off
set sqlformat csv

spool tablename_output.csv

select /*+ parallel */ * from <tablename>;

spool off
```

or else:

```
set term off
set feed off

spool tablename_output.csv

select /*+ parallel */ field1 || ';' || field2... from <tablename>;

spool off
```

Comment: Thanks @Saxon. I don't have access to db server and my code will be running on cloud and will access the DB which is on-prem via thin jdbc client. I assume I may not be able to make a system call in this scenario,

Comment: You don't need to access the DB server to connect via sqlplus. You only need to make a system call on machines that have an oracle client properly configured. You simply invoke a shell script or a groovy script that does the job.